# Bootstrap 4 font size em differs in Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Angular 8 with bootstrap v4.4.1 (package.json -> "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.2.1",). My requirements:

- support responsive design (accomplished with bootstrap)
- make browsers render all elements consistently

I thought that the second point is solved by bootstrap as well. The problem is this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark menu-item">
  <i class="fas fa-align-center"></i>
</button>
```

Chrome shows button twice as large as Mozilla Firefox. I then added [Bootstrap Reboot](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/reboot/) (as a normalizes, but it doesn't change anything)

This is my whole global `styles.scss`:

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.css";
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
@import "variables.scss";

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: $gray-light;
}

.menu-item {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

How do I get that font size renders equally in Firefox and Chrome. Specifying `px` works, but latest trends go to `em` or `rem`. Doesn't Reboot overrides the `em`?

Setting this works, but not really sure this is the best approach:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: $gray-light;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is default font size defined by Mozilla Firefox browser.

[image]

If you set `font-size: 100%` it will use default size defined by the browser. You have to set font-size in pixels. From there on you just use `<em>` or `<rem>`.

```
   html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: $gray-light;
  /* Browser settings can override font-size, therefore we set it here. This is also
  with accordance with bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/ */
  font-size: 16px;
}

.my-div {
  font-size: 2em; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `styles.scss`:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-size:100%;
  background-color: $gray-light;
}
```

Make sure that none of the browsers are zoomed in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to reset zoom. Font sizes in different browsers are different a little bit but they shouldn't be too different.

Comment: Actually the problem is in Mozilla Firefox Font settings.